# How to auto center crop ImageView Android?

Tags: android, imageview, crop

I made a listView images. My goal that each item of my listView have the same height of 100dp. I encounter a problem that my imageView is resized automatically, but does not take the entire space of the parent.

**Here is my current result and objectif result :**

[image: Resized Image objectif]

**Does anyone know the option to add to make crop center automatically?**

Comment: Show your Layout files.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood correctly. It must be either of the two, that you want, I guess.

In your image view set the attribute

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

to fit the `ImageView` completely.

You can choose

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

to crop Center.

Comment: It's centerCrop that he wanted, in the example given the image is trimmed

Comment: Ya. I wasnt able to view the image at the time, I was answering this post. But I could get it later..

Answer (score 42):

i know it's late but maybe it would be helpful for someone coming on this question page by using android:scaleType="centerCrop" image is centered but it is cropped from all sides so it would be better to use this property instead that is fitCenter and with this use another property too to maintain the aspect ratio

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"            
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Answer (score 7):

Are you aware of the cropping options on ImageView?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

You will just apply these as an attribute in your XML:

like:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but android: scaleType = "fitXY" does not keep the proportions of the images in the imageView so I prefer android: scaleType = "centerCrop".

Answer (score 4):

in java: `imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);`