# Remove the white space frame from the splash image

Tags: android

I am making an image with my s4 Samsung device which I am trying to put as splash image for my app but I am facing problem that the Image is being displayed  with wide white space Frame. How can I remove it?

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout       
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_draw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_background"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have displayed the Image in LinearLayout as the code below before but it was shown horozintal:

**Code before:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:background= "@drawable/splash_background"
    >

</LinearLayout>
```

**Screenshot before trying the solution of Hasan:**

[image]

**After trying hassan solution android:scaleType="centerCrop"**

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_background"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

> Any graphical designer while working on a mobile app. should take in
>   consideration the mobile development guide lines.

When designing a splash screen image the designer have two solutions:

1. produce an image that have a solid background or transparent with no gradient. in this case the image can be displayed in the centre with a background color.
2. produce an image that doesn't look ugly when it's cropped from top/bottom or left/right(depends on screen ratio). in this case you use `centerCrop` as `scaleType`.

Comment: I have tried it with `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` but without seccuss.

Comment: what did you have? maybe your image resolution is too low.

Comment: check the following question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747879/how-to-auto-center-crop-imageview-android it have some pictures to demonstrate that.

Comment: I have added picuture to illustrate it.

Comment: Remove rotation and adjusttruebouns for now. And check the result.

Comment: Yes it Looks much better now Thanks :). Please remove these attributes from your answer. I have already markerd it as answered.