# Android crop bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, crop

I need to programmatically crop specific area from bitmap, like blue area on this image [image]

How I can do it?

Comment: I think its similar Question [Android Crop Bitmap][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908604/android-crop-center-of-bitmap

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747879/how-to-auto-center-crop-imageview-android

Comment: @GIRIDHARANAR no it's not similar, there is only center square crop, but I need arbitrary region

Comment: @MicheleLacorte that's not what I need, thank you

Comment: you mean that you want ONLY blue part or blue part and whats inside it?

Comment: @ErfanMowlaei sorry for inaccuracy, I need all area, blue part and whats inside it

Comment: take a look at my answer, no problem pal

Comment: please mark as answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: @ErfanMowlaei Ok, I'll try it as soon as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just like below:

```
// x refers to width, y refers to height
//first find startx, starty, endx, endy
Bitmap blueArea = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, startx, starty, endx, endy);
```