# Android setBackgroundResource maintain aspect of image

Tags: android, background-image, textview

When setting the background of a TextView with setBackgroundResource, how do you maintain the aspect ratio of the image

`view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.day_background);`

Even though my image is a round circle, it still comes out oval due to the fact that the TextView is landscape.

UPDATE:
The issue is that I'm trying to use the background to set an image that I do not want to scale.  From what I understand now of the background of a textview you can't do that (it doesn't make sense, its the background of the textview; it has to cover the entire textview).

The answer is to wrap the textview around a a relative view, center it and then add an image view which is also centered behind it.  The image view then can be controlled in size and set appropriately.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9362168/3736955

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto center crop ImageView Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747879/how-to-auto-center-crop-imageview-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in the UPDATE.  Wrap the TextView in a RelativeView and then use an ImageView as the background which can be controlled.